# Junit Test (Mockito, PowerMock) a class with void method and private value

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

some sample code like:
(I just added some more details)

```
 public class A {
      @Autowired
      private Data data;

      @RequestMapping(value="/Boo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public void Boo(){        
        data.someMethod();       
  } 
}
```

I want to test the someMethod() is run or not.

I have tried @First answer but got some error message like below:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.exceptions.StackTraceCleanerProvider$1.isIn(Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;)Z
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.filter(StackTraceFilter.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.filter(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:23)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:44)
```

Comment: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html. But you'd better start using constructor injection.

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace and an [mre] that produces this error?

Answer (score -1):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @Spy
    private Data data;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // execute
        this.a.Boo();

        // verify
        Mockito.verify(this.data).someMethod();
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no need to `spy` on `a`. Also this just verifies that `someMethod()` is called, its not actually `run` as the OP has formulated it. But I would assume that this is the correct answer.

Comment: @second, thanks. \@InjectMock annotation should be used alone, indeed.
As a way to run real methods on Data instance, we could define it as a Spy. But this would also mean that we're bringing logic under the responsibility of other class, which is not ideal for Unit Testing.

Comment: thanks, Jose. But it seems not working for me. I got the error message like below: